# You do not have permission... spring security shiro

Tags: grails, spring-security, shiro

I am currently working on implementing the spring security shiro plugin but seem to be running into an issue with permissions. Below is my setup. I get a 'You do not have permission to access this order...' when accessing a resource I should have access to.

**Domain Class**

```
class Permission {

   Account user
   String permission

   static constraints = {
      permission unique: 'user'
   }
}
```

**Controller**

```
if(!subject.isPermitted("todo:edit:${todo.id}")){
    flash.message = "You do not have permission to access this order..."
    forward(controller:'todo', action:'list')
    return
}
```

**Bootstrapped data**

```
account.addToPermissions("todo:save")
account.addToPermissions("todo:edit:" + todo.id)
account.addToPermissions("todo:update:" + todo.id)
account.addToPermissions("todo:remove:" + todo.id)
account.save(flush:true)
```

The permissions match up, but unsure where the hickup is. The `isPermitted` should work without issue now.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The user class needed to have a hasMany of the Permission object. In older versions the user class had a hasMany of permission Strings. I also had to remove the constraints portion in the Permission domain class.

```
class Account{
    static hasMany = [ permissions: Permission ]
}


class Permission {

   Account user
   String permission

   static constraints = {
   }
}
```